# Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI "ws:localhost:3000"

Tags: flutter, dart

I will try connect Websocket with flutter

```
   final _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
    Uri.parse('ws:localhost:3000'),
  );
```

It working with web platfrom but i run it in ios or masOs destop,... it return Error:

```
Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI http://:0/localhost:3000
```

Please help me!
Thanks for any support

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), especially when that image is 100 times larger than needed for the message. You could have at least cropped it to a reasonable size.

Comment: @KenWhite oh sorry about that, updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
Uri.parse('ws://localhost:3000')
```

Ios doesnt accept url if its not in the format of a normal url in websockets

Comment: Oh it  worked with "ws://localhost:3000"

Comment: @kenWhite i totally agree with you. Sorry for that. Updated my answer